# May I know that there is a special structure or solution on this linear fractional optimization?

Tags: optimization, closed-form

I am not familar with the optimization problems, but I want to know a very simple formulation:
\begin{array}{cc}
{{\max_\mathbf{x}}} & \frac{\mathbf{a}^{T}\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{b}^{T}\mathbf{x}}\\
{\rm s.t.} & x_{1}+x_{2}+\cdots+x_{n}\leq c
\end{array}
where $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$are $n\times1$ real vectors with positive elements, $c$ is also a constant, and $x_i\geq0$.

I have found that this form is called linear fractional programming. But is there a closed-form solution of the above problem? Or whether the solution has a special structure? Thanks.

Comment: It can be reformulated as ordinary linear programming task: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming#Transformation_to_a_linear_program

Comment: Thanks @mvw . Yes, I know that. For the ordinary linear fractional programming, I can follow the method from wiki and reformulate it to the LP. But I want to know whether it will be different for this special form. For example, the analytical solution can be obtained?

Comment: I see. Have you tried to derive such for the not so abstract cases $n \le 3$?

Comment: For the case $n=2$, it is shown that the result is always ${x_1=c,x_2=0}$ or ${x_1=0,x_2=c}$.

Comment: @mvw. This result is reasonable, since if we take the partial derivative to the objective function, it is non-zero in general, which means the maximum value should be on the boundary. But I don't know whether it is hold in a general $n$, and the result is still all 0 except one $x_i=c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution $\mathbf{x}^\star$ to your optimization problem is given by

$0 < x_j^\star \leq c $ for $j = \arg \max_i  \frac{a_i}{b_i}$,

$x_i^\star = 0$ for $i\neq j$.

How can we proof this?
Having a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming#Duality we can formulate the dual problem of your fractional problem as
\begin{equation}
\min \lambda ~~~\text{   subject to}~~ [-\mathbf{I},\mathbf{1}]^T \mathbf{u} + \lambda \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{a} \\
 -[\mathbf{0}^T,c] \mathbf{u} \geq 0 \\
\mathbf{u} \in \mathrm{R}^{n+1}_+, \lambda \in \mathrm{R}.
\end{equation}
Here $\mathbf{I}$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, $\mathbf{1}$ is the $n \times 1$ vector having 1s everywhere, and $\mathbf{0}$ is the  $n \times 1$ vector having 0s everywhere.

- From the second line of the dual problem follows $u^\star_{n+1}=0$.
- Then, the first constraint of the dual problem results in $-u_i + \lambda b_i = a_i$ for all $i=1,\dots, n$.
  As $-u_i\leq j$, it follows $\lambda \geq \frac{a_i}{b_i}$ for all $i=1,\dots, n$.
- Therefore, to minimize $\lambda$ we have to find the smallest $\lambda \geq \frac{a_i}{b_i}$. Therefore, the solution to the dual problem is $\lambda = \frac{a_j}{b_j}$ where
  $j = \arg \max_i  \frac{a_i}{b_i}$.
- This proofs the optimality of $\mathbf{x}^\star$ for the primal problem as the value of the target function concides with the optimum value of the target function of the dual problem.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Schad. The answer is correct and I am clear now.

Comment: You are welcome, Chang!